# Integrating Gamma and Pochhammer functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

Could anybody explain why *Mathematica* gives different results with:

```
With[{n = 6, z = 0.34}, 
  { Integrate[ Log[ Gamma[t + n]/Gamma[t]], t] /. t -> z, 
    Integrate[ Log[ Pochhammer[t, n]], t] /. t -> z}]
```

> ```
> {9.83259, 19.319}
> ```

recalling that by definition
`Gamma[t + n]/Gamma[t] == Pochhammer[t, n]`?

The same issue  for different values of $n$ and $z$.

Comment: Hi Nasser!  I cleaned up the formatting of your question.  Check out https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help for more info on formatting.  I personally like to put code in a block delimited by \`\`\`.

Comment: Added the `[scoping]` tag, because without `With` it's evaluating correctly for both expressions.

Comment: @m0nhawk, what do you mean by "evaluating correctly for both expressions"?

Comment: @Alx `N@{Integrate[Log[Gamma[t + n]/Gamma[t]], t] /. {n -> 6, t -> 0.34}, 
  Integrate[Log[Pochhammer[t, n]], t] /. {n -> 6, t -> 0.34}}`

Comment: Thank you, m0nhawh. I haven't seen N@ before, I guess still a lot to learn. Do you know what is the problem with With?

Comment: Indefinite integrals are anti-derivatives, they can differ by an arbitrary constant and still both be valid anti-derivatives. Compare with `With[{n = 6, 
  z = 0.34\`15}, {Integrate[Log[Gamma[t + n]/Gamma[t]], {t, 0, z}], 
  Integrate[Log[Pochhammer[t, n]], {t, 0, z}]}]`

Comment: @m0nhawk I'm not sure `With` is to blame, I see the same discrepancy with `n = 6; z = 0.34; Integrate[Log[Gamma[t + n]/Gamma[t]], t] /. t -> z
Integrate[Log[Pochhammer[t, n]], t] /. t -> z`

Comment: @ChrisK I agree, I found the same discrepancy with `Integrate[Log[Pochhammer[t, n]], t] /. n -> 6` and `Integrate[Log[Pochhammer[t, 6]], t]`. But I narrowed it down after I posted a comment.

Answer (score 6):

Calculating indefinite integrals we can expect different expressions, at least different by a constant.  It is not surprising since the expressions in logarithms migth be negative and so issues with different branches of logarithm would appear. Let's calculate indefinite integrals:

```
 ints = With[{ n = 6}, Assuming[ t > 0, 
                         { Integrate[ Log[ Gamma[t + n]/Gamma[t]], t],

                           Integrate[ Log[ Pochhammer[t,n]], t]}]]
```

> ```
>  { t Log[Gamma[6 + t]/Gamma[t]] + t LogGamma[t] - t LogGamma[6 + t] - PolyGamma[-2, t] 
>    + PolyGamma[-2, 6 + t],
>
>   -6 t + Log[1 + t] + 2 Log[2 + t] + 3 Log[3 + t] + 4 Log[4 + t] + 5 Log[5 + t] 
>    + t Log[t (1 + t) (2 + t) (3 + t) (4 + t) (5 + t)]}
> ```

We use a rational counterpart of approximate number `0.34` to find the difference in an exact form:

```
 FullSimplify[ ints[[1]] - ints[[2]], t == 17/50]
```

> ```
>  3 (-5 + Log[2] + Log[Pi])
> ```

It appears that the both expressions differ by the above number which equals to

```
N @ %
```

> ```
>  -9.48637
> ```

as in the question.  This difference is the same for every argument as one could expect.

```
Plot[ ints, {t, 0, 2}, Evaluated -> True, PlotStyle -> Thick, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Of course definite integrals calculated in appropriate ranges don't differ.

```
ints2 = With[{n = 6, z = 17/50}, 
             { Integrate[ Log[ Gamma[t + n]/Gamma[t]], {t, 0, z}], 
               Integrate[ Log[ Pochhammer[t, n]], {t, 0, z}]}];

 ints2[[1]] == ints2[[2]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

It should be noted that symbolically the both integrals can take different forms, e.g.  consider the integrands without logarithms:

```
With[{ n = 6}, Assuming[ z > 0,{ Integrate[ Gamma[t + n]/Gamma[t], {t,0,z}],
                                 Integrate[ Pochhammer[t,n], {t,0,z}]}]]
```

> ```
> { Integrate[ Gamma[6 + t]/Gamma[t], {t, 0, z}], 
>   60 z^2 + (274 z^3)/3 + (225 z^4)/4 + 17 z^5 + (5 z^6)/2 + z^7/7}
> ```

although the system knows that the integrands are equal:

```
FullSimplify[ Gamma[t + n]/Gamma[t] == Pochhammer[t, n]]
```